# How to show that a sequence in $L^2(-R,R)$ satisfy a certain condition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $d >0.$ Prove that $\{ e^{i k x / d} \}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is a frame for $L^2(-R,R)$ if and only if $0 < R \leq d \pi.$

The frame condition implies that for $\{ f_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$
$$A \cdot \| f \|^2 \leq  \sum_{k=1}^m \left\vert\langle f, f_k \rangle\right\vert^2 \leq B \cdot \| f \|^2, ~ \forall f \in L^2(-R,R).$$
How to incorporate the square integrable to function space to prove the given result. I'm struggling with this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_k(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2r}}e^{i \pi k x/ r}$. The Fourier series main theorem is that $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal (unitary) basis of $L^2(-r,r)$.

If and only if $ R \le r$, then $f \in L^2(-R,R)$ can be seen as $f1_{|x| < R} \in L^2(-r,r)$,

so that
$$f1_{|x| < R} =  \underbrace{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}}_{\text{in } L^2(-r,r)} \langle f,e_k\rangle e_k$$
And Parseval's theorem gives
$$\|f 1_{|x| < R}\|^2_{L^2(-r,r)} = \|f\|^2_{L^2(-R,R)} = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} |\langle f,e_k\rangle|^2$$

Now if $\forall x, f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, then $|\langle f,e_k\rangle| = |\langle f,e_{-k}\rangle|$, and you also have  $\frac{1}{2}\|f\|^2 <\sum_{k=0}^\infty |\langle f,e_k\rangle|^2 < \|f\|^2$

Comment: thank you. The $e_k(x)$ that you took was different to what is given in the problem. Does it matter. And how did you get the second line, "If and only if....."

Comment: @ManMath no it doesn't change anything, just take $d = r / \pi$, $f_k = \sqrt{2r} e_k$. And $L^2(-R,R) \subseteq L^2(-r,r)$ if and only if $R \le r$, which is obvious

Comment: @ManMath now did you really mean $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ at the end ? in that case a little more work is needed

Comment: its's my mistake. I just mentioned the definition that I know for a finite index set. Clearly, here the set is the set of integers, so has to start from zero.

Comment: @ManMath Ok. Otherwise it works too, because $r > R$ means that  $\langle 1_{|x| < R}, e_m  \rangle =C \ne 0$ for some $m \ge 1$, so that $\|f\|^2 < \frac{2R}{|C|} \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle f,e_k\rangle|^2$

Comment: appreciate this. Thank you for spending time to explain this. I'll go through it carefully.